# Can an immediately invoked property reference the object to which it is assigned?

Tags: javascript

I have some code:

```
var obj = {
    foo : true,
    bar : (function() {
        if (obj.foo) {
            return qux;
        }
    })()
};
```

My issue is that `qux` will never be returned because `obj` does not exist when `bar` executes, since `bar` is an immediately invoked function.

There is a solution:

```
var obj = {
    foo : true
};

obj.bar = (function() {
    if (obj.foo) {
        return qux;
    }
})();
```

But I find the former code to be more straightforward. Is there a way to accomplish this or am I stuck with the latter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that cannot be done. *edit* wait I'll post a possibility. *edit again* no that was a dumb idea. I'm sticking with my original sentiment :)

Comment: Why do you think you need an IIFE there?

Comment: I don't see the point in having the bar property set immediately, especially when it depends on foo, which is always true...

Comment: @Samy This is why I asked about the need for an IIFE; the example is obviously over-simplified to the point where it's difficult to tell what the real need is.

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. I think it's closer to what you were looking for than the selected answer.

Comment: @Pointy Was your idea the one I posted?

Comment: @plalx no it wasn't nearly as creative as that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to accomplish this or am I stuck with the latter?

Assuming `qux` is not a local variable to the IIFE, you can just use this (you still need to split the object declaration, though):

```
var obj = {
    foo : true
};
obj.bar = obj.foo ? qux : undefined;
```

Comment: It seems like this is the consensus. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you must split the literal declaration. Or use a constructor function.

Comment: @bfavaretto You could always use some helper functions to gain some sort of syntaxic sugar like in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's actually *a way* or at least an idea on how to do it, but it's a bit ridiculous.

*NOTE: I haven't implemented delayedMembers that depends on other delayedMembers.*

```
function delayedObj(o) {
    var k, v;
    for (k in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(k) && (v = o[k]).__delayedMember__) {
            o[k] = v.fn.call(o);
        }
    }
    return o;
}

function delayedMember(fn) {
    return {
        __delayedMember__: true,
        fn: fn
    };
}
```

Then you can define your object like:

```
var obj = delayedObj({
    foo : true,
    bar : delayedMember(function () {
        return this.foo;
    })
});

console.log(obj.bar); //true
```

Comment: Interesting, but I agree with the "a bit ridiculous" part! :)